# QGIS log Error displayed within Quick OSM Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, quickosm

I am having an issue using the Quick OSM Plugin. I am using QGIS V3.4. I am following this tutorial linked below.

[QGIS Training Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/foreword/preparing_data.html)

The issue I am facing is occuring at **Step 9** of section **1.2.1 'Try Youreself Create OSM based Vector Files**. After downloading the sample data used within the 'QGIS Traning Manual'

I get this error message --> "Error in the QGIS Logs, QuickOSM Panel, please report it to GitHub". I have reported this issue, however was wondering if this is my human error or if the software or data has the issue and can any one solve this?

Comment: what is the error in the log file?